# C++ "OR" operator

Tags: c++, programming-languages, codeblocks

can this be done somehow?

```
if((a || b) == 0) return 1;
return 0;
```

so its like...if a OR b equals zero, then...but it is not working for me.
my real code is:

```
bool Circle2::contains(Line2 l) {
    if((p1.distanceFrom(l.p1) || p1.distanceFrom(l.p2)) <= r) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a side-note your code formatting in the second one is horrible. It's easy to miss the `return 1;` and think that `return 0;` is the "then" clause, and not the implicit "else" clause.

Comment: Please use `return true` or `return false`. Yes, I'm aware that compilers will correctly interpret this, but... if you're going to declare bool, at least use the bool keywords.

Comment: @codeinchaos, i didn't even see the `return 1` !

Comment: You are looking for the ICON programming language, not C++; it's a language where you can write things like `if (i|j|k) == (10|20)` with the meaning "either i, j or k are equal to 10 or 20" ... http://www.cs.arizona.edu/icon/

Comment: A good question on the basics, because the compiler will *accept* these fragments and then do something that a beginner may find surprising.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to write the full expression:

```
(a==0)||(b==0)
```

And in the second code:

```
if((p1.distanceFrom(l.p1)<= r) || (p1.distanceFrom(l.p2)<=r) )
    return 1;
```

If you do `((a || b) == 0)` this means "Is the logical or of `a` and `b` equal to 0. And that's not what you want here.

And as a side note: the `if (BooleanExpression)return true; else return false` pattern can be shortened to `return BooleanExpression;`

Comment: LOL, it's a stampede! +1 for your mad speed-answering skills.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the condition separately each time:

```
if (a == 0) || (b == 0))
    bla bla;
```

When you do

```
if ((a || b) == 0)
    bla bla;
```

it has a different meaning: (a || b) means "if either a or b is non-zero (ie. true), then the result of this expression is true".
So when you do (a||b) == 0, you are checking if the result of the previously explained expression is equal to zero (or false).

Answer (score 2):

The C++ language specifies that the operands of `||` ("or") be boolean expressions.

If `p1.distanceFrom(l.p1)` is not boolean (that is, if `distanceFrom` returns int, or double, or some numeric class type), the compiler will attempt to convert it to boolean.

For built in numeric type, the conversion is: non-zero converts to true, zero converts to false. If the type of `p1.distanceFrom(l.p1)` is of class type `Foo`, the compiler will call one (and only one) user defined conversion, e.g., `Foo::operator bool()`, to convert the expression's value to bool.

Answer (score 2):

Fun with templates:

```
template <typename T>
struct or_t
{
  or_t(const T& a, const T& b) : value1(a), value2(b)
  {
  }

  bool operator==(const T& c)
  {
    return value1 == c || value2 == c;
  }

private:
  const T& value1;
  const T& value2;
};

template <typename T>
or_t<T> or(const T& a, const T& b)
{
  return or_t<T>(a, b);
}
```

In use:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int a = 7;
  int b = 9;

  if (or(a, b) == 7)
  {
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It performs the same comparison you would normally do, though, but at your convenience.

Comment: And now go for short-circuit version... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you really want something like this:

```
bool Circle2::contains(Line2 l) {
if((p1.distanceFrom(l.p1) <= r) || (p1.distanceFrom(l.p2) <= r)) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have lot of that code, you may consider a helping method:

```
bool distanceLE (Point p1, Point p2, double threshold) {
    return (p1.distanceFrom (p2) <= threshold)
}

bool Circle2::contains (Line2 l) {
    return distanceLE (p1, l.p1, r) && distanceLE (p1, l.p2, r);
}
```

If you sometimes have <, sometimes <=, >, >= and so on, maybe you should pass the operator too, in form of a function.

In some cases your intentions by writing this:

```
if ((a || b) == 0) return 1;
return 0;
```

could be expressed with an bitwise-or:

```
if ((a | b) == 0) return 1;
return 0;
```

and simplified to

```
return  ! (a | b);
```

But read up on bitwise operations and test it carefully. I use them rarely and especially I didn't use C++ for some time.

Note, that you inverted the meaning between your examples 1 and 2, returning true and false in the opposite way.

And bitwise less-equal doesn't make any sense, of course. :)

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't support any construct like that. Use `if (a == 0 || b == 0)`.

Comment: It does, but they have different meaning.

Comment: @NikitaRybak: I meant semantically. `(a || b) == 0` will be true if both `a` and `b` are false.

Comment: yeah im looking for function as in discrete mathematics, so `(a || b) == 0` would be true if both are true and false if atleast 1 is false

Answer (score 0):

Your condition should be `(a == 0 || b == 0)` or `(p1.distanceFrom(l.p1) <= r || p1.distanceFrom(l.p2)) <= r)`

Answer (score 0):

C++ isn't that smart. You have to do each comparison manually.

```
bool Circle2::contains(Line2 l) {
if((p1.distanceFrom(l.p1) <= r) || (p1.distanceFrom(l.p2) <= r)) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to know, in C++, `0` is false and `1` is true. With that in mind, to answer your first question (Code 1):

```
return !(a && b);
```

If one of the bools is false then `a && b` is false so `!(a && b)` is true i.e., `1`, otherwise both a and b are true so `a && b` is true so `!(a && b)` is false i.e., `0`. You can also do (Code 2)

```
return !a || !b;
```

but this performs up to three logical operations whereas the first one performs up to two, which is less. The equivalence of these two expressions is one of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

To fix your second code (Code 3):

```
bool Circle2::contains(Line2 l) {
    return p1.distanceFrom(l.p1) <= r || p1.distanceFrom(l.p2) <= r;
}
```

If you want to avoid the double `<= r` (Code 4):

```
bool Circle2::contains(Line2 l) {
    for (auto p : { l.p1, l.p2 }) {
        if (p1.distanceFrom(p) <= r) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

The `for` loop initializes an anonymous array of two values, `l.p1` and `l.p2`, and checks each one and returns `true` immediately if it finds a satisfying point. That means that it short-circuits, like `||`. `false` is only returned after both points were found not to satisfy. I would recommend using something like Code 3 because two points to check is simple enough to do with a simple `||` expression. In an alternate scenario where you had to check a lot of points, something like Code 4 would be useful.